# Can I Reload webpack plugins after webpack --watch rebuild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

I am currently dynamically adding templates to my `HtmlWebpackPlugin` like this:

```
var PROD = JSON.parse(process.env.PROD_ENV || '0');

function prepareHtml(){

    console.log(PROD);
    pages = [];
    config = require('./src/core/js/config-modulo');
    var size = Object.keys(config).length;
    for(var i = 0; i<size; i++){

        for(var j = 0; j<config[i+1].num_pages; j++){
            if(!(fs.existsSync('./src/und'+(i+1)+'/'+(j+1)+'.html'))){
                var modelo = '<html lang="pt-br">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n<title>Livro On-line</title>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="config-livro.js"></script>\n</head>\n<body>\n<div class="page">\n<div class="header"></div>\n<div class="conteudo">\n<!-- ================================================================== -->\n<!-- ================================================================== -->\n</div> <!-- End conteudo -->\n</div> <!-- End page -->\n<!-- Scripts -->\n</body>\n</html>';
                fs.outputFileSync('./src/und'+(i+1)+'/'+(j+1)+'.html',modelo);
            }
            var page = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: '../../und'+(i+1)+'/'+(j+1)+'.html',
                template: './src/und'+(i+1)+'/'+(j+1)+'.html',
                });
            pages.push(page);
        }
        var newconfig = 'UNIDADE_NUMBER = '+(i+1)+';\n'+
                        'UNIDADE_NAME = "'+config[i+1].nome_unidade+'";\n'+
                        'LINK_PDF = "'+config[i+1].link_pdf+'";\n'+
                        'PAGES_TOTAL = '+config[i+1].num_pages+';';

        var caminho = 'dist/und'+(i+1); 

        if(PROD){ 
            console.log(PROD);
            fs.outputFile(caminho+'/config-livro.js', newconfig, function (err) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./src/core/js/config-modulo')];
    console.log(pages);
}
```

Calling this `prepareHtml()` function and then concatenating it's results to my plugins array.

The problem is that when webpack --watch gets triggered, the function works fine but the plugin's configurations are not updated, I know that because the new files are not tracked nor handled.

I'm using the `WebpackPreBuildPlugin` to rerun the function at every build.

Is there any way I can "rebuild" my plugins everytime webpack --watch is triggered?

EDIT: 
I am adding the plugins like this:

```
plugins: [
        new WebpackPreBuildPlugin(function(stats) {
            prepareHtml();
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '../css/livro.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
          })
    ].concat(pages)
```

Where the "pages" variable is being generated by the `prepareHtml` function.

I know this works because the first time I run webpack --watch all the files get generated and are properly tracked, the problem really is adding new files dynamically, the function runs fine, the "pages" array is correctly created, it just doesn't get fed to the plugins array.

Comment: I don't see where you'd actually add those `HtmlWebpackPlugin`s into the plugin list though?

Comment: I use .concat(pages) to add the array of instances created inside the function (its a global variable)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's easily doable, since [plugins are just things that are "applied" to the compiler internally](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/a8687890f72b48d5135315f86bca788407d30b68/lib/webpack.js#L42-L50), i.e. they set up hooks in the compiler; you'd have to carefully only apply new plugins to the compiler yourself.

Instead, if you really need this functionality, I'd suggest writing your own Webpack plugin that wraps those dynamically created instances of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and runs them at the same stage `HtmlWebpackPlugin` would, with your dynamic configuration.

Otherwise... it would just be easiest to note in your readme that you have to re-start the watch process if you add new pages. :)